# Optimizing an Azure App Service for Static Content

Tags: web-server, azure, static-content, azure-app-services

I have a "Basic" **Azure App Service Plan** hosting multiple **App Services**. One of those App Services contains *exclusively* **static content** (i.e., `html`, `css`, `js`, `png`, &c.).

#### Question

What *server-side* configuration settings are available to me in **Azure** to optimize for static content delivery? My objective is to minimize resources used by the App Service Plan, while also maximizing responsiveness to clients.

> **Note:** I am *not* looking for advice on optimization of *client-side* files, such as bundling and minification.

#### Current Settings

Currently, I have the following set in my `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <staticTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="*/*" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

#### Related Questions

I'm hoping for something similar to [an excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/a/256100/327786) to [a similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/255849/iis-7-5-optimizations-for-a-site-serving-only-static-content) pertaining to **IIS 7.5** from a number of years ago. Obviously, many of those remain pertinent. Are there additional settings I should be considering for **Azure** specifically? For example, are there ways to disable support for server-side preprocessors such as **ASP.NET** that might reduce unnecessary resources?

Comment: Also, I recognize this is a somewhat open-ended question. I hope that's appropriate here. If not, kindly let me know and I'll find a better forum for it.

Comment: What are you concerned about mainly, cost or performance? If cost is a concern you can use Azure storage to host static sites directly.

Comment: @SamCogan That's a really good question. Resource utilization (and, therefore, cost) is my primary concern; I want resources to be prioritized for other **App Services** under the same **App Services Plan** which _do_ require dynamic pre-processing. **Azure Storage** was also my initial instinct; ultimately, however, that's impractical due to the case sensitivity. (Customers may be typing in directory names, and so it's important that the URLs remain case insensitive.)